# Error while migrating to Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I used a version 2.14 and migrated to 3.0.1, and I'm having several problems, like this one below, please help me. My application has 5 thousand downloads in the play store and I need to keep updating.

```
Error: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
Researched the following localization: 
  file: / C: / Program Files / andr / gradle / m2repository / com / android / tools / build / gradle / 3.0.1 / gradle-3.0.1.pom 
  file: / C: / Program Files /andr/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar 
  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0. 1 / gradle-3.0.1.pom 
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar 
Required by: project:
```

Comment: Please use English language on This site

Comment: it's done. Thank